# Set string value into spinner while moving from one activity to another

Tags: android

- I need to set the open_time string value to spinner.In previous
  activity I'm getting the response as string.
- then I passed that string value to bundle from FirstActivity to
  SecondActivity.

**Coding** :

**SecondActivity.java:**

```
  String open_time;

  Spinner staticSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.static_spinner);

  Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();

        if (bundle != null) {
                open_time = bundle.getString("open_time");

 }
```

- My only problem is ,While entering into SecondActivity the open_time
  String value have to set into Spinner.Anyone help me with this.

**Edit:** I have tried `fromSpinner.setPrompt(open_time);` .But that doesn't worked for me.

Comment: you can set value in spinner using id or index of the item.
use staticSpinner.setSelection(index);

Comment: @androidnoobdev In my FirstActivity I am getting one string value from json.that one have to set in spinner of SecondActivity.is it possible?

Comment: I hope you have list of options that you display in spinner and you store in arraylist or any collection. so get index of that item and pass it to new activity and set that index item selected in second activity spinner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by using this below code:

```
int s3; 

s3 = fromSpinnerAdapter.getPosition(open_time);
 fromSpinner.setSelection(s3);
```

Answer (score 0):

Android Spinners need adapters. So you should prepare a simple adapter for them.

```
String[] list = new String[] {open_time};

ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);

staticSpinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
private ArrayList<String> list;
private int selectedItem = -1;

ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);

staticSpinner.setAdapter(adapter);

staticSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

    Spinner selectedSpinner = (Spinner) adapterView;

    switch (selectedSpinner.getId()) {
        case R.id.sp_actions:

                String row_data = sp_actions.getSelectedItem();
                Log.d(TAG, "" + row_data);

                // pass these variable to new activity and call setSelected method
                selectedItem = list.indexOf(row_data);

            break;
        }
}
```